# How to draw square on the button at the center using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

How to draw a square on the button at the center (like stop button)?

In this code that I try it be like a rectangle and full of the button:

```
void ButtonDraw(Button *b)
    {
        if(b)
        {
            /*
             *  We will indicate that the mouse cursor is over the button by changing its
             *  colour.
             */
            if (b->highlighted) 
                glColor3f(0.7f,0.7f,0.8f);
            else 
                glColor3f(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f);
            /*
             *  draw background for the button.
             */
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2i( b->x     , b->y      );
                glVertex2i( b->x     , b->y+b->h );
                glVertex2i( b->x+b->w, b->y+b->h );
                glVertex2i( b->x+b->w, b->y      );
            glEnd();

           /*draw red square on the button*/
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex2i(b->x, b->y);
            glVertex2i(b->x+b->w, b->y);
            glVertex2i(b->x+b->w, b->y + b->h);
            glVertex2i(b->x, b->y + b->h);
            glEnd();

            /*
             *  Draw an outline around the button with width 3
             */
            glLineWidth(3);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code as code, not as screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested Donald Duck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way is to not draw a red rectangle the same size as the button, but instead draw a square. Here is the most basic way to do this:

```
/*draw red square on the button*/
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
const int SQUARE_SIDE = 6; // Or however long you want a side
// Calculate the centre of the button rectangle
const int xMid = b->x + b->w / 2;
const int yMid = b->y + b->h / 2;
// Trace a square around the centre
glVertex2i(b->xMid - SQUARE_SIDE / 2, b->yMid - SQUARE_SIDE / 2);
glVertex2i(b->xMid - SQUARE_SIDE / 2, b->yMid + SQUARE_SIDE / 2);
glVertex2i(b->xMid + SQUARE_SIDE / 2, b->yMid + SQUARE_SIDE / 2);
glVertex2i(b->xMid + SQUARE_SIDE / 2, b->yMid - SQUARE_SIDE / 2);
glEnd();
```

The above code calculates the middle of the button then draws a square around it. For production code you'd of course check that you didn't overlap the edges of the button, and use floats to deal with rounding issues, etc.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer Ken Y-N.

Comment: @Melo234: if it solved your problem, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/222560).

Comment: I'm already accept your answer. Thanks again for remind me because this is the first time that I use StackOverflow.